# Modeling product variations in Rails3/Mongoid with an embeds_many / embedded_in relation....?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I know this is a (somewhat) common question but I'm a newbie and I always appreciate a second (or 100th) pair of eyes on a problem I'm been noodling.

I'm wondering if I'm taking the right approach here -- I'm trying to model a product with several variations and the associated gift certificates sold against that product.

A product, for example, for a restaurant might be a "tasting menu for 2" whereas variations might be "food only", "with partial wine pairing", and "with full wine pairing", etc.  (just an illustrative example).

Here's a distilled version of what I've come up with:

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  has_many :gift_certificates
  embeds_many :variations
end

class Variation
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embedded_in :product
  has_many :gift_certificates      
end

class GiftCertificate
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :recipient, type: String
  field :amount, type: Float

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :variation
end
```

So when we create a GiftCertificate, it's defined as belonging to both a product and a variation (is that correct?).  An example might be a "$200 gift certificate for tasting menu for 2 [product] with partial wine pairing [variation]", etc.

I feel like the embeds_many / embedded_in relation here for Products/Variations is ideal as it fits the profile for when it should be used:  I'll never be accessing a product without its variation, and I never need to access a variation independant of a product -- they go hand-in-hand.

So the question is whether I'm doing this the right way.

I've managed to massage the basic CRUD forms into working using ryanb's excellent [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem, with a bit of tweaking.  Editing the Products & Variations are easy (the basic use case), but the trouble I'm having comes when working with the Gift Certificates.

Mongoid is giving me a bit of trouble ... the GiftCertificate belonging to both a product and its variation seems kludgy, and I have to manually set the GiftCertificate.variation each time I do a find, i.e.

```
@gc = GiftCertificate.find(params[:id]) // as normal
@gc.variation // ==> nil, doesn't work by itself
@gc.variation = @gc.product.variations.find(@gc.variation_id) // Have to manually set this
@gc.variation // Now this works as it's supposed to
```

Anyway, before I go on -- would love to get some thoughts on the above.

Thanks in advance!